# How to implement DI in Spring MVC.?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a confusion in Dependency Injection in Spring MVC.

First Code:-

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private Userdao udo;



    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Positions> plist() {
        return udo.plist();
    }
}
```

It is working Fine.
I would like to implement Dependency Injection in this class.Am doing right or wrong?

second code:-

```
`@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private Userdao udo;

    public UserServiceImpl(Userdao udo) {
        this.udo = udo;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Positions> plist() {
        return udo.plist();
    }
}
```

Its not working.`ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.xxx.Services.UserService com.xxx.java.HomeController.uservice; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl' defined in file [D:\xxxWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\abcd\WEB-INF\classes\com\xxx\ServiceImp\UserServiceImpl.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.xxx.ServiceImp.UserServiceImpl]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.xxx.ServiceImp.UserServiceImpl.<init>()`

I am a beginner .please help me to solve this.How to implement DI in Spring MVC.

Comment: Your first version already gets the `Userdao` injected because of the `@Autowired` annotation. Not sure what you want to achieve with the second version.

Comment: I learned from Google that How to implement DI .From there i got private Userdao udo;

    public UserServiceImpl(Userdao udo) {
        this.udo = udo;
    }  for DI implementation.For that i implement this.Is it a DI in my first version?If yes then please explain for easy to understand.@ Henry

Answer (score 1):

You can do this two ways.

1. You can use field based autowiring. But in this case you will need a default constructor.

   ```
   @Service
   @Transactional
   public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

       @Autowired // field based DI
       private Userdao udo;

       // default constructor
       public UserServiceImpl() {}

       @Override
       @Transactional
       public List<Positions> plist() {
           return udo.plist();
       }
   }
   ```
2. You can use constructor based dependency injection. To do this simply move your @Autowire annotation to your constructor. And remove it from the field.

   ```
   @Service
   @Transactional
   public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

       private Userdao udo;

       @Autowired // constructor based DI
       public UserServiceImpl(Userdao udo) {
           this.udo = udo;
       }

       @Override
       @Transactional
       public List<Positions> plist() {
           return udo.plist();
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: Thank You@Paul Trzyna. i needed  exactly this code.

Answer (score 1):

First setup is alright, and should work.

In the second setup you're getting following exception

```
class [com.xxx.ServiceImp.UserServiceImpl]: No default constructor found;
```

Which means what it says, since you've defined a constructor `public UserServiceImpl(Userdao udo)` Spring can't find an no-argument constructor.

You can either remove this constructor and use the first one or you can define the no argument constructor yourself.

You shouldn't actually need to define a constructor in a bean as you're not going to create bean object yourself. You would only need it if you're autorwiring constructor arguments.

If you're trying to autowire constructor then you can do it like below.

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private Userdao udo;

    @Autowired //autowired constructor, instead of the field
    public UserServiceImpl(Userdao udo) {
        this.udo = udo;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Positions> plist() {
        return udo.plist();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*In simple words:* If you define a constructor *(overloaded)* then you must use the `@Autowired` annotation on the constructor, if you do not define a constructor, then you must use the `@Autowired` annotation for each `Object` you need to add as dependency injection. For example:

**With constructor overloaded:**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private final Userdao userDao;
    private final RoleDao roleDao;

    @Autowired
    public UserServiceImpl(Userdao userDao, RoleDao roleDao) {
        this.userDao = userDao;
        this.roleDao = roleDao;
    }

}
```

**Without constructor overloaded**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Autowired
    private RoleDao roleDao;

    // default constructor
    public UserServiceImpl() {}

}
```

*Defining a constructor with a single `@Autowired` is better than having many objects `@Autowired`*